# problem after adding row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the below code to add row in jqGrid

**Updated**

I click on the checkbox to see `id's` by using your code below

```
 $(document).delegate('#list1 .jqgrow td input', 'click', function () 
{ 
    /*var grid = $("#list1 .jqgrow");
    var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');*/
    var mydata = $("#list1").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
    var idToDataIndex = $("#list1").jqGrid('getGridParam','_index');
    var id;
    for (id in idToDataIndex) {
        if (idToDataIndex.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            console.info(id+", "+mydata[idToDataIndex[id]]['cfgName']);

        }
    }
    console.info("maxid "+id);

});
```

Here is my output in firebug

[image]

How i am getting `jqg1` in place of id? may be this is creating the problem

```
function addRow(cfgid,cfgname,hostname,cfgDesc,productId,cfgType,updateDate,emailAddress,absolutePath)
{   
var myrow = {cfgid:cfgid, '':'', cfgName:cfgname, hostname:hostname, cfgDesc:cfgDesc, productId:productId,hostname:hostname,cfgType:cfgType,updateDate:updateDate,emailAddress:emailAddress,absolutePath:absolutePath};
$("#list1").addRowData(cfgid, myrow,"first");

$("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid");
$("#list1").sortGrid('updateDate', false, 'desc');
}
```

updateRow works fine as i used `currentrow` but how to use max id for adding a new row in `addRow`?

```
function    updateRow(cfgid,cfgname,hostname,cfgDesc,cfgType,updateDate,emailAddress,absolutePath)
{
      $("#list1").delRowData( currentrow );
  $("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid");

var myrow = {cfgid:cfgid, '':'', cfgName:cfgname, hostname:hostname, cfgDesc:cfgDesc, productId:updateproductid,hostname:hostname,cfgType:cfgType,updateDate:updateDate,emailAddress:emailAddress,absolutePath:absolutePath};
$("#list1").addRowData(currentrow , myrow);
$("#list1").sortGrid('updateDate', false, 'desc');
$("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

but is seems when the row is added it gets a duplicate `id` because when i try to select that row, 2 rows get selected.

My full jqGrid code

```
 var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
         $('#configDiv').empty();
            $('<div width="100%">')
            .attr('id','configDetailsGrid')
            .html('<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>')       
            .appendTo('#configDiv');    

            var grid = jQuery("#list1");

            grid.jqGrid({

              datastr : xml,
              datatype: 'xmlstring',
              colNames:['cfgId','','Name', 'Host', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By',''],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
                  {name:'',index:'', width:15, align:"right",edittype:'checkbox',formatter: "checkbox",editoptions: { value:"True:False"},editable:true,formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                  {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
              ],
              pager : '#gridpager',
              rowNum:10,
              scrollOffset:0,
              height: 'auto',

              autowidth:true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              xmlReader: {
                  root : "list",
                  row: "com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },
              onSelectRow: function(id,status){
                  var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                  configid = rowData['cfgId'];
                  configname=rowData['cfgName'];
                  configdesc=rowData['cfgDesc'];
                  configenv=rowData['cfgType'];

                  var ch =  jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked');
                  if(ch) {
                            jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
                  } else {
                            jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',true);                       
                  }

                  rowChecked=1;
                  currentrow=id;
                  },
              onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
                  if(index==2)
                  {

                        $(xmlDoc).find('list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo').each(function()
                        {
                            //alert($(this).find('cfgId').text()+" "+configid);
                            if($(this).find('cfgId').text()==configid)  
                            {
                                configname=$(this).find('cfgName').text(); 
                                configdesc=$(this).find('cfgDesc').text();
                                configenv=$(this).find('cfgType').text();
                                filename=$(this).find('fileName').text();
                                updatedate=$(this).find('updateDate').text();
                                absolutepath=$(this).find('absolutePath').text();
                                productname=productMap[$(this).find('productId').text()];
                            }
                        });

                  }
               }

            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @Oleg: Can you see this question please

Comment: If you want to post me a message you should write comment having "@Oleg" to **one of my previous answers**. If you just write the same comment on your new question where I didn't write any answer or my comment before the stackoverflow will just ignore the message and I will not receive any notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use always the same `id="1"` as the first parameter of `addRowData` in the `addRow`. If you do this you will receive the `id` duplicates on the page which is not permitted on a HTML page.

It seems that the `cfgId` column are unique in the grid. So if you have only one grid with `cfgId` column on your page you can modify the `addRowData` in the `addRow` to the following:

```
$("#list1").addRowData(cfgid, myrow,"first");
```

Another way is to use `$.jgrid.randId()` method as the rowid parameter of `addRowData`

```
$("#list1").addRowData($.jgrid.randId(), myrow,"first");
```

or the `undefined` value:

```
$("#list1").addRowData(undefined, myrow,"first");
```

In the last case the jqGrid will call `$.jgrid.randId()` internally to generate the unique rowid.

Comment: I updated my question with a snapshot to show that in place of getting the `id` i am getting some crap value

Comment: @Ricky: I don't understand which code you used to produce the screenshorts. The results shows, that you had `cfgid=undefined` for the row having `abcd` in the `cfgName`. In the case the rowid will be generated by `$.jgrid.randId()`. It is an integer (`1` in your case) with the `jqg` prefix. So you should verify your `cfgid` values. If you not sure, that the `cfgid` are not unique you can directly use `undefined` in the all `addRowData` calls.

Comment: Thanks by mistake it was always calling updateRow, and so my addRow was not getting called.