# Auto Search functionality for Schools/Universities using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building a website where the user should have the capability of adding their School/University. I have noticed in LinkedIn, when i tried to type in my school name , it showed up a auto search box with all the schools, beginning with the letter i typed. How can i achieve the same functionality?

Do they save all the Universities in their database ? Or is there any Open webservices i can use that will show all the Schools/Universities ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called "Auto Complete" and the text boxes are enabled with that.  These allow you to filter the data required according to the characters you type in.

Please see this post for auto-complete feature implemented using jQuery.

[Razor: Auto-complete text box inside jqGrid, How to bind values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961325/razor-auto-complete-text-box-inside-jqgrid-how-to-bind-values)

The example shown in that page lists all from the database.  However, as a next phase, you can as well extend this feature to look for a WCF exposed service for universe of schools/colleges.

FYI" "GetSkillNameAutocomplete" is a method in the controller that takes a string parameter as an input (the search string) and gets the value(s).

Hope this helps!